# Best pratice for having a daily updated cache for multithreading application in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

In my application, I'd like to have a cache that will be updated daily by an expensive operation (for example, fetching from remote and computing locally). The idea is every day, it will fetch and compute the latest cache for today. And at any time of today, any thread should be able to read from/write to the daily cache. And it's fine to serve the old data when the expensive operation is running daily and should not block any requests at any time.

I have written a simple code to illustrate the idea but not sure if it's the best practice or even correct in terms of multithreading.
For example,

- is `volatile` required?
- What will happen if there is a cache reassignment finished in the middle of a get or put.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

```java
public class DailyCache {
    private volatile ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> cache;

    public DailyCache() {
        cache = expensiveCalculation();
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)
                 .scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> cache = expensiveCalculation(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return cache.get(key);
    }

    public void put(String key, String value) {
        cache.put(key, value);
    }

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> expensiveCalculation() {
        // an expensive operation to fetch the cache for today
    }
}
```

Comment: The biggest issue I see is conflicts between calls to `put` and the expensive daily computation. Entries that are `put` while the daily computation is in progress may be lost when the cache is replaced. Is that acceptable for this use case? Is the `put` method really needed?

Comment: Yes, this is acceptable, and `put` is needed in my use case.

Comment: You need to use an external persistent cache. Something like Redis. Otherwise your cache is lost when your application crashes, and when you scale, every instance needs to run the expensive operation. An external persistent cache can address both

Comment: There is no "best practice".  There is only "what meets your requirements".  Even if there are multiple ways to meet your requirements, there is no simple way to determine which of them will be "best" ... because most of the "goodness" criteria will be unstated (by you) and not scientifically measurable.  What you are really wanting is someone with a magical crystal ball to tell you which of a number of possible futures (depending on your choices) will give the best outcome.  Of course, that's not possible.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt - It could be acceptable that the cache is lost.  There may be no need to scale up.  And if you are able to scale up by partitioning the data space among the servers you don't need a shared cache.  Finally, a shared cache may itself turn into the performance bottleneck if you scale up enough.  (But at least you didn't say it was "best practice" :-) )

Comment: Allowing a path for scaling is a good idea. To do that, as others have said, the cached info will need to be shared by multiple accessing processes, and you'll want to make it persistent. If that sounds like huge overkill for your current use case, fine. It's still possible to design for scalability now and implement later. Organize interfaces carefully so they can be replaced by RPC stubs, and persistent storage can replace in-memory. Avoid as many singleton patterns as possible. Each will need to become a network service later and a potential bottleneck.

Comment: @StephenC just having an external cache isn't a best practice. it depend on your exact use, constraints (does the third part service have limits? how expensive is the compute? how easy is it to get a managed persistent cache resource in your deployment environment). with a read-heavy solution, it may be good enough to update a single blob in an s3-like service from a batch job, and have each app poll that and cache the result locally). I'm just suggesting that the OP consider that apps crash and may need to scale.

Comment: "Allowing a path for scaling is a good idea."  - Not necessarily.  It could also be described as over engineering.  Or premature optimization.  It depends on the context.  The point is that you (Gene and Erwin) are making assumptions about the nature of the OP's application and then making recommendations **based on those assumptions**.

Comment: @StephenC There's no over-engineering in proper interface design with Law of Demeter in mind. That's all I'm recommending. It is not over-engineering. It's good engineering. Unfortunately it's not widely practiced.

Comment: Suggesting the use of an external cache when there is no >demonstrated< need for an external cache is over-engineering.  And unfortunately, over-engineering >is< widely practiced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Executor service

First of all, you need to capture the reference returned from the call `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`. You must store that reference somewhere in your app for eventual shutdown. If you neglect to shut down an executor service, it’s backing pool of threads may continue to run after your app exits, like a zombie ‍♂️.

And, by the way, for a single-threaded executor service, call the convenience method [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

## Replace entries

If you are using a thread-safe collection, then I would replace individual elements during your update. Do you have a need to replace all the map entries simultaneously? If so, say so in your Question.

If you do *not* have a reason to replace the entire map, change your code to mark your `cache` as `final`. If you establish the map’s existence well before the first attempt to access it, and you never replace it, then no need to mark it as `volatile`.

Another thing: It’s generally best to make your fields the most general type that fits. So in this case, `ConcurrentMap` rather than locking yourself into `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```java
public class DailyCache {
    private final ConcurrentMap< String, String > cache;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService ses;

    public DailyCache() {
        this.cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>() ;
        this.expensiveCalculation();
        this.ses = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ; 
        this.ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> cache = expensiveCalculation(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS );
    }

    public String get( String key ) {
        return this.cache.get( key );
    }

    public void put( String key, String value) {
        this.cache.put( key, value );
    }

    public void expensiveCalculation() {
        // A series of expensive operations to replace each element/entry of the `Map` cache.
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        // Gracefully shut down the scheduled executor service held in var `ses`. 
        …
    }
}
```

One advantage to this entry-replacement approach is that fresh data arrives to the user faster, with the early replacements being made available to the calling code while later replacements have yet to be made.

## Replace map

### `volatile`

If you have a reason to replace the entire map all at once, rather than replacing individual entries, then you should make the `cache` declaration non-`final`, and `volatile`.

```java
public class DailyCache {
    private volatile ConcurrentMap< String, String > cache;
…
```

But I prefer a different approach. Due to the change in its definition specifically, and the complexity of concurrency in general, I expect the `volatile` keyword is not clearly understood by all programmers.

### `AtomicReference`

So I would use an [`AtomicReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) object instead, to hold a reference to your current map object. Seeing that `AtomicReference` declaration should make your intentions obvious to another programmer.

An `AtomicReference` is a thread-safe holder for a reference to an object.

- *var ➤ reference ➤ object*
  With a conventional reference, such as the `cache` variable seen above, we are one step away from the map object: The `cache` variable holds a reference which at runtime takes us to the `ConcurrentMap` object floating within the heap somewhere.
- *var ➤ reference ➤ object ➤ reference ➤ object*
  With an `AtomicReference`, we are *two* steps away from the desired object. The `cache` variable seen below is a reference to an object whose content is the reference to yet another object.

An `AtomicReference` is a little weird to think about at first, because in Java we think of a variable like `cache` above *being* the object, even though we know it is one step away from an object. In contrast, an `AtomicReference` makes us quite conscious of the fact that we are manipulating a reference to an object containing a reference to an object. For example, notice the `.get().get(…)` and `.get().put(…)` calls below.

```java
public class DailyCache {
    private final AtomicReference < ConcurrentMap< String, String > > cache;
…
```

Here is the complete class, revised for an `AtomicReference`.

```java
public class DailyCache {
    private final AtomicReference < ConcurrentMap< String, String > > cache;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService ses;

    public DailyCache() {
        this.cache = new AtomicReference<>( new ConcurrentHashMap< String, String > () ) ;
        this.expensiveCalculation() ;
        this.ses = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ; 
        this.ses.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> cache = expensiveCalculation(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS );
    }

    public String get( String key ) {
        return this.cache.get().get( key );
    }

    public void put( String key, String value) {
        this.cache.get().put( key, value );
    }

    public void expensiveCalculation() {
        ConcurrentMap< String, String > concurrentMap = … // An expensive operation to produce a new `ConcurrentMap`.
        this.cache.set( concurrentMap ) ;
    }

    public void shutdown() {
        // Gracefully shut down the scheduled executor service held in var `ses`. 
        …
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer your questions:

> Q: is it "the best practice"

There are [No Best Practices](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164).  If you haven't done so already, take the time to read that.

This question is unanswerable ... and not even meaningful.

Hint: it is time to remove "best practice" from your vocabulary ... and start questioning the wisdom of people who tell you that something is "best practice".

> Q: is `volatile` required?

Maybe.  It depends on whether it is possible for the reference in `cache` to change.

- If it is possible, then the `volatile` is required.
- If it is not possible, then the `volatile` *may not be* required.  But in that case you *should* declare the variable as `final`.  If you do that, then the JLS guarantees that all threads will see the correct value for variable.

In your code, it looks like you are periodically assigning a new value to `cache`.  If so, then it needs to be `volatile`, or you need some other way to ensure that all worker threads see the updated `cache` value.  (There are other ways ... but this is starting to smell of premature optimization.)

> Q: What will happen if there is a cache reassignment finished in the middle of a get or put.

If the `get` or `put` call starts before the assignment, then they will definitely operate on the old cache.  If not, it is not it will depend on whether the fetch of the `cache` occurs before or after the assignment.  That is unpredictable.

---

There is one other thing that you don't seem to have considered.  You say:

> And it's fine to serve the old data when the expensive operation is running daily and should not block any requests at any time.

But you have not said if it is OK (or not) for the old cache to be updated while the new cache is being built.  For example, consider this sequence of events:

1. Start rebuilding cache
2. Cache rebuilder updates key1 -> value1 in the new cache
3. The main application reads and updates key1 -> value2 in the old cache
4. The cache is replaced.

Now we have the application running with the new cache, but the new cache contains a value1 for key1 that is older than the most recently used value (value2).

If that breaks your application, then you need a way to solve it.  There will be ways ... but it will depend on aspects of your application logic that you haven't mentioned.   For example, the scenarios in which regular application threads will do cache `put` operations.